# What are some of the new directions of research in Elliptic Curve Cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am searching for some new research areas in ECC for my masters' project. My professor suggested me to go for Image Encryption using ECC. But I am clueless as to what are the new directions possible in such an area.

Comment: Did they really suggest that to you? If so, change the advisor. The ECC, although can be used for encryption, is not used for encryption. Key exchange ECDH, Signatures edDSA are the main uses. If you are really interested, you can start reading a book that contains Elliptic Curve chapter.

Comment: Well they did suggest that. And existing research papers like Singh and Singh(2015) Image Encryption using ECC and subsequently another improved one in 2017 were the ones I used for reference. Arent they using ECC directly for image encryption?

Comment: Could you link the paper?

Comment: This is the 2017 paper.https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0030402617309208

Comment: This is their google scholar page and contains all their work till now.https://scholar.google.co.in/citations?user=FoGUkB0AAAAJ&hl=en

Comment: Can you write their encoding scheme and request their code?

Comment: I havent requested for their code. Though I  have implemented the 2015 paper in python as per its given encoding scheme using the tinyec library where I just use the ec.Point(curve,x,y) function to put the point on the curve. It works. I haven't completely implemented the 2017 paper though.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you working on isogeny-based assumptions specially within its new framework "Group Actions". Check this paper
https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1188.pdf
There is a wide space for research, specially that the hardness of these assumptions are not so clear and we need more analysis.
They are candidates for quantum cryptography.
And Finally you may also think about realizing more cryptographic primitives from these assumptions.